# Drupal 8 Unique field in profile registration

Tags: validation, drupal, registration, drupal-8

Is it possible to make a field unique in the registration for Drupal 8 ?

I have added a field named field_account_nr and I would like it to be unique, so it has to validate that the value does not exist in a current user yet. I would also like to check if the value exists in an array.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

```
//Get all the users in the system
$allUsers = User::loadMultiple();

$accountNumbers = [];

foreach ($allUsers as $user){
//Get each user their account nr and add it to the array
  array_push($accountNumbers, $user->get('field_account_nr')->value);
}

if (!in_array($currentAccountNr,$accountNumbers)){
  //Its unique
}
```

This is out of the top of my head so you might need to tweak it but this will get you started.

Hope this helps!